# Linux not sending ICMP with iptables `--reject-with`

Tags: linux, firewall, iptables, icmp, packet

Using `iptables` I am trying to reject packets (I want to return an ICMP message).

```
iptables -A FORWARD [...] -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreach
```

The packets are dropped but using `tcpdump` I can see no `ICMP`. What gives ? Am I doing something wrong ? Do I have to flip some `sysctl` or anything ?

Kernel is: `2.6.32-5-openvz-686`

**Please** don't suggest "use `DROP` instead of `REJECT`".

Comment: Are outgoing icmp packets allowed in your iptables rules?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the packets in question have matched your rule to reject?  Do you see the counter associated with that rule being incremented when you look at the verbose output (`iptables --list --verbose`)?

Have you tried disabling all the other iptables rules aside from that one to make sure that no other rules are interfering?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are hitting the FORWARD chain? You can add a rule to log all the matching packets.

```
 iptables -I FORWARD [...] -j LOG --log-prefix "FORWARDED"
```

If you after adding that rule you cannot see anything on /var/log/messages you probable are using the wrong chain (INPUT instead of FORWARD?) or the wrong conditions.